# How to deal with NA in index for Panel data

Tags: r, plm

I want run regression in panel data. There is NA in my index (ID,time). I do not want to delete NA in index.

```
Result<-plm(TBL~Tang+Prof+LnSALES+MB,data=Panel,model="within",index=c("Firms","Time"))
```

When I the above code, it returns:

```
at least one couple (id-time) has NA in at least one index dimension in 
resulting pdata.frame 
to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
Error in model.matrix.pFormula(formula, data, rhs = 1, model = model,  : 
NA in the individual index variable
```

Without delete NA, how can I run panel regression with NA in index?
Thanks

Comment: Just think through the issue a little... If there's an `NA` in your index column, you have an observation of your variables that you don't know who it belongs to. How then is `plm` supposed to sort out the fixed effects for your `within` model?

Comment: Hi thanks, i mean just omit NA in index when regressing, not delete them from the data

Comment: How does `Result <- plm(TBL ~ Tang + Prof + LnSALES + MB, data=Panel[which(!is.na(Panel$Firms)), ], model="within", index=c("Firms", "Time"))` work?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works

Comment: @duckmayr do you want to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Helix123 yes, thanks for reminding me. I used the comment format first since I couldn't be sure it was a working answer without 1412MM's data, but hadn't gotten around to adding an answer after their feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are just looking to omit observations where your index is `NA`, you can do this:

```
Result <- plm(TBL ~ Tang + Prof + LnSALES + MB,
              data=Panel[which(!is.na(Panel$Firms)), ],
              model="within", index=c("Firms", "Time"))
```

#### Explanation

`data=Panel[which(!is.na(Panel$Firms)), ]` tells `plm()` to use as data a subset of `Panel` where `Panel$Firms` is not `NA`. Then you cannot have the issue where

```
at least one couple (id-time) has NA in at least one index dimension in 
resulting pdata.frame
```