# remove NA from indices in panel regression: Follow-up problem

Tags: r, na, tibble

I found this answer for excluding NAs in the indices for the plm function (
[How to deal with NA in index for Panel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242997/how-to-deal-with-na-in-index-for-panel-data) ) and included it in my code and duplicated the **exlusion** since I have NAs in both indices for the plm:

```
result <- plm(VarX ~ VarY + VarZ, data = mydata[which(!is.na(mydata$ID)),!is.na(mydata$year)], index = c("ID","year"), model="within")
```

Now, R gives me a error message saying:

> Error in `vectbl_as_col_location()`: ! Must subset columns with a
> valid subscript vector. ℹ Logical subscripts must match the size of
> the indexed input. ✖ Input has size 6 but subscript `j` has size 2366.

and I have no idea what it means or how I can possibly deal with it.

Comment: I am not sure but this doesn't look right: `mydata[which(!is.na(mydata$ID)),!is.na(mydata$year)]`, I don't know what is contained in mydata but it seems that it should be `mydata[!is.na(mydata$ID) & !is.na(mydata$year),]`

Comment: thank you for your correction, it managed to do the regression! thanks a lot!

Comment: The error actually stems from subsetting itself, more specifically from subsetting a tibble (as `vectbl_as_col_location` is from the package tibble). Thus, this is not related to package `plm`. My suggestion is to first prepare your data (and subset to exclude the NA's in the index variables), then to create a `pdata.frame` and input the pdata.frame into `plm`'s `data` argument.